# Creating background images in fireworks

Tags: html, css, image, fireworks

Basically i want to have a two tone image for my background in a site im making. The top say 120px will be a shade of gray and the bottom will be white! Now normally i would just make a 1px line with the top half gray and the bottom white, obvious enough but what i need for this particular site is to be able to continuously scroll down the page keeping the background white and not repeating the entire pattern if you get me??

any ideas or suggestions would be great! stumpped here....

Comment: So what's the problem? Make a 120px gray image and put it in the background, no-repeat;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a grey picture thats 120px tall and 1px wide and use `background-repeat: repeat-x;` I guess.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i was trying to figure out, good man!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as

```
background: #ffffff url(images/sample-pattern.jpg) repeat-x
```

This way your image would repeat along the top but then the rest of the page would have the white background.